# Explain read a message object once with WCF?

Tags: wcf, idispatchmessageinspector

I have a MessageInspector which logs the messages that come through?  What is the reason why you can only read a Message once and must create a copy? I have seen the documentation from MSDN that I need to create a buffered copy, but I don't know why it is implemented this way?  Can someone explain it to me?

```
private static void SendRequest(string request)
{
var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://urltoservice.svc/MethodToCall");
req.ContentType = "text/xml";
req.Method = "POST";

using (var stm = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    using (var stmw = new StreamWriter(stm))
    {

        stmw.Write(request);
    }
}


byte[] myData;
using (var webResponse = req.GetResponse())
{

    var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    myData = ReadFully(responseStream);
}

// Do whatever you need with the response
string responseString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myData);
}
```

If I don't have access to the server part or the ability to change the MessageInspector to use a buffered copy of the message, can I modify the message above to make a copy of a stream?  If so, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: See [Data Transfer Architectural Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347789.aspx) which states *A message body can be retrieved only once. This makes it possible to work with forward-only streams.* - so this leads me to believe it's a performance optimization measure, above all, that lead to this architectural decision

Comment: That is for advanced developers as the article states.  I do appreciate it though.  I have no idea what a forward-only stream is?

Comment: Whoever downvoted? can you explain why?

Comment: A forward-only stream is a stream that can be read only in forward direction - once from the start to the end. Once you're done, there's no way to go back and start again - and you cannot jump around in the stream during reading. Less capable (in some ways), but typically a lot faster.

Comment: OK is there a way around this like copying the stream to another stream and setting the position to 0.

Comment: Yes - [see this blog post on how it's done](http://www.bryanavery.co.uk/post/2010/04/23/WCF-Message-can-only-be-read-once.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s - That is not exactly what I meant. I meant can I alter my SendRequest method to copy into another stream.  I will post code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your message into a buffer and play with it.
More details about working with messages you can find on the following link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx